# C# MVC AntiForgeryToken генерирует не правильный Hidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, input, hidden

Данные в контроллере подготавливаются верные и на представление приходят корректные данные. Имеется вот такая незаурядная модель:

```
public class InfoServiceSystem : Tuple<bool, InfoServiceSystemBase>
{
    public InfoServiceSystem() : base(false, new InfoServiceSystemBase()) { }

    public InfoServiceSystem(bool isAvailable, InfoServiceSystemBase item) 
       : base(isAvailable, item) { }

    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get { return this.Item1; }
    }

    public InfoServiceSystemBase ItemBase
    {
        get { return this.Item2; }
    }
}
```

Свойства `IsAvailable` и `ItemBase` добавил для удобства (так как Item1 и Item2 нельзя изменить, а более удобно использовать осмысленные имена).

Имеется представление содержащее следующий код:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         ...
         <table id="tblInfoSystems" class="table table-bordered">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     ...
                 </tr>
             </thead>

        <tr>
            <td class="align-left">Система...</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SystemsContext.ElSystemInfo.IsAvailable)</td>
            ...
```

Отображается все верно, вот только если взглянуть на код страницы, то увидим следующее:

[image: Код страницы]

Как видим, `input`, являющийся `hidden` - генерируется `false`. Ранее `IsAvailable` у меня был одним из полей класса `InfoServiceSystem` и все работало корректно, но появилась необходимость в разделении и после этого появилась странное поведение...какие предположения будут по поводу такого странного поведения и варианты решения? Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Если убрать:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

и писать везде:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SystemsContext.ElSystemInfo.IsAvailable)
```

то все равно поведение не то, которого хотелось бы.
Внесу небольшую поправку, изначально оно и должно генерироваться значением по умолчанию (в нашем случае `false`), но перед отправкой значений с формы - заполняется нужным значением и в контроллер приходит то, что нужно (в нашем случае `true`). Раньше заполнялось, а теперь нет. Почему так?

Comment: <del>Подождите, этот хидден в таблице относится к чекбоксу, т.к. через GET/POST нельзя отправить false-значение чекбокса. Хидден к токену должен быть где-то вне таблицы.</del> Извиняюсь, вопрос не правильно понял.

Comment: @kmv, сейчас попробую вынести

Comment: @kmv, вынес хиддены вне таблицы - работает так же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело оказалось в том, что у `Tuple` не редактируемые свойства. И их нельзя переопределить. Поэтому значения из `false` в `true` не изменялись после отправления данных с формы и в контроллер приходили не те значения, которые ожидались.